# How to enable Google Analytics Demographics and Interest Reports - Tried everything

Tags: google-analytics

So I have been trying to get this to work for the past 3 weeks, reading seemingly every article on this - and still I get "There is no data for this view".

I am using Classic Analytics and I have done as google advised in replacing the the ga.js with dc.js. I also have "Display Advertiser Features" turned on. I clicked to validate the tracking code several times, but nothing happened. Many people recommended to skip the validation and it would eventually show up.

As you probably know, google says it will work within 24 hours, but it's been much longer than that. Also, I assume the problem isn't from an insufficient amount of user data since there has been over 1,000 visitors since I have implemented this.

I noticed that most of the problems with this are dated back to Nov '13 and haven't seen any useful information recently, so I assume this hasn't been much of an issue for people.

Any help with this... well you will be a superhero to me.

Here is my [site](http://buildthefire.com/).

Comment: Can you share the site?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two instances of Google Analytics:

1. Yoast Google Analytics Plugin - `UA-41290502-1` (dc.js is not enabled)
2. Google Analytics Tracking Code - `UA-41290502-2` (dc.js **IS** enabled)

If you'd like to keep the Yoast plugin, there should be an option to add the dc.js support through there, but I would removed the other instance of the tracking code.

When you're looking at trying to view the demographics reports, what property are you using? My guess is that you're using the `UA-41290502-1`. Trying viewing the other property `UA-41290502-2`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I left the Yoast plugin enabled because I was using that from the beginning to track universal analytics, so that has my all time data. Recently, I added the the classic (dc.js) once I decided to track demographics. From there, I was viewing the dc.js property. I read that having both enabled wouldn't interfere with each other, but I just deactivated the plugin to see a change. Nothing as happened so far, but that could change.

Comment: I also get this note from goolge when trying to view the demographics data: "Some data in this report may have been removed when a threshold was applied." However, I've looked up on that as well, and don't see the conflict.

Comment: I believe both codes you had implemented were Google Analytics (ga.js) and not Universal Analytics. Universal Analytics doesn't support demographics...yet.

Comment: You were right about that not being Universal Analytics. I just switched it back to the plugin and disabled the second tracking code. Thanks for your help, I'll wait on it and hopefully it works...and hopefully they get this for Universal soon